# Extracting Activation maps from trained neural network

Tags: keras, conv-neural-network

I have a trained cnn model. I am trying to extract the output from each convolutional layer and plot the results to explore which regions of the image have high activations. Any ideas on how to do this?

Below is the network I have trained.

```python
input_shape = (3,227,227)   
x = Input(input_shape)
# Conv Layer 1

x = Convolution2D(96, 7,7,subsample=(4,4),activation='relu',
                            name='conv_1', init='he_normal')(x_input)

x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2), name='maxpool')(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(x)

# Conv Layer 2
x = Convolution2D(256, 5,5,activation='relu',name='conv_2', init='he_normal')(x)



x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2),name='maxpool2')(x)

x = BatchNormalization()(x)
x = ZeroPadding2D((2,2))(x)

# Conv Layer 3

x = Convolution2D(384, 3,3,activation='relu',
                            name='conv_3', init='he_normal')(x)


x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2,2),name='maxpool3')(x)    
x = Flatten()(x)

x = Dense(512, activation = "relu")(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)

x = Dense(512, activation ="relu")(x)

x = Dropout(0.5)(x)


predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)

model = Model(inputs = x_input, outputs = predictions)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2664) and the FAQ [How can I obtain the output of an intermediate layer?](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-can-i-obtain-the-output-of-an-intermediate-layer). It seems the easiest way to do that is defining new models with the outputs that you want. For example:

```
input_shape = (3,227,227)   
x = Input(input_shape)
# Conv Layer 1

# Save layer in a variable
conv1 = Convolution2D(96, 7, 7, subsample=(4,4), activation='relu',
                      name='conv_1', init='he_normal')(x_input)
x = conv1
x = MaxPooling2D(...)(x)
# ...
conv2 = Convolution2D(...)(x)
x = conv2
# ...
conv3 = Convolution2D(...)(x)
x = conv3
# ...
predictions = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(x)
# Main model
model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=predictions)
# Intermediate evaluation model
conv_layers_model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=[conv1, conv2, conv3])

# After training is done, retrieve intermediate evaluations for data
conv1_val, conv2_val, conv3_val = conv_layers_model.predict(data)
```

Note that since you are using the same objects in both models the weights are automatically shared between them.

A more complete example of activation visualization can be found [here](https://github.com/philipperemy/keras-visualize-activations). In that case they use the `K.function` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have a query here. After this step, model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=predictions), I will load the weights, model.load_weights('past_trained_weights.h5') and if i do this step -> conv_layers_model = Model(inputs=x_input, outputs=[conv1, conv2, conv3]), will the weights corresponding to these layers be retained?

Comment: And in the above code, shouldn't it be, conv1_val, conv2_val, conv3_val = conv_layers_model.predict(data)

Comment: 1) Yes, I think the weights should still be the same across both models, since you are using the same tensor objects. I haven't really tried it, but you can test it by running the whole thing a couple of times and checking that you get the same intermediate results (as opposed to random values due to random weight initialization). 2) Yes, of course, thanks, I changed it.